# LVP flooring against a wood riser for railing

Tags: flooring

I have a wood riser around my staircase leading downstairs that the railing sits on. It is not tall enough to use quarter rounds, what should my next steps be to hide the cut edge or keep them secure? It will be both short and length ways that will meet the riser.

Comment: A picture showing measurements might help.  If the difference is enough, quarter round could be cut down some, or there might be different sizes/types of moulding.

Comment: Smaller quarter-rounds or a bead of caulking...

Comment: @Ecnerwal is caulking appropriate for LVP?  I guess if it's glued down and not floating.

Comment: It's hard to get a true idea of what you are up against without a pic or 2.  You may be able to use shoe molding. It's only 1/4 inch thick and 5/8 to 3/4 inch high.  Ecnerwal is correct on caulk also. It can be used on a floating LVP floor.